# two dimensional array increement

Tags: c, arrays

I need to bin a hist variable like this, which is in a loop for p and bin,

```
hist[p][bin] = hist[p][bin] + 1;
```

When I comment this line, the code works( verified the p and bin variable print). However when I include this line the program terminates with segmentation fault. Further examining the bin variable gives me a huge negative integer ( -214733313 ), which leads to segmentation fault. The program runs normally when I comment this line and the bin variables are normal integer. Do I miss an obvious thing here?.

Thanks

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense. Also,there is not enough information to solve your issue. Include the declaration of the 2D array and tell us the values of `p` and `bin`

Comment: "Do I miss an obvious thing here" - yes, including an [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *in your question* that reproduces your problem. Obviously you're indexing out of range. Why that is, along with your code, remains a mystery. My code-clairvoyance hasn't worked since my New Year's bender.

Comment: for(p=0;p<8;p++){
 function(....,angle)
 bin = (int) angle[0]/2.0 + 1;
 hist[p][bin] = hist[p][bin] + 1;
 }

Comment: I can save you some time on that too. Is your pseudo code seg-faulting?

Comment: Sorry for double posting, I'm bit new here.

for(p=0;p<8;p++){
 function(....,angle)
 bin = (int) angle[0]/2.0 + 1;
 hist[p][bin] = hist[p][bin] + 1;
 }

I'm calling a function to calculate the angle and slicing it with a interval 2 degree and binning it to produce a histogram. I need to do this for different p. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Edit your question to add relevant information.

Comment: Yes, only this part gives segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a -2147... you are basically reaching the max size of a signed integer, or 2^31 -1 (32 bits, 4 bytes, a C int).

If we assume this, then it's safe to say you're hitting memory where $FFFFFFFF is in it. I only ever see this in unallocated, generally random memory. It could be safe to assume then you are going out of bounds with your ask. You could have hist[p][bin] be the maximum memory of your array, and adding 1 is going out bounds.

Comment: Yes, This I could understand. But, when I comment this line // hist[p][bin]++ //, the program executes normally and the variable bin and p are within the bound. ( here bin is 0 to 180 and p is 0 to 7). Only it gives me a problem with // hist[p][bin]++ ; //, if I  execute without increment of 1 .i.e) hist[p][bin] it works. I mean bin is -2147..

Comment: You'd have to give us your source code for further help.